# How to change the root (administrative name) in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

How to change the root (administrator name) in ubuntu if  the password of old user is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code. It is probably best to do this without being logged in

```
usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
```